# I have a flink program,but it can not write some data into redis

Tags: apache-kafka, redis, flink-streaming

I have a Flink program that receives information from Kafka, performs some word frequency statistics, and then writes the results to the Redis server. After running it, it can see the information it prints to read from Kafka, but I don't see the results in my Redis

```
    package com.swjd

    import org.apache.flink.api.common.restartstrategy.RestartStrategies
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time
    import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.RichSinkFunction
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.extensions._
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaTopicPartition
    import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis

     import java.util.Properties
     import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


     object KafkaRedisContinueal {


      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
        env.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(
          3,
          org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time.of(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // 间隔
        ));
        env.setParallelism(3)



        val kafkaProps = new Properties()
        kafkaProps.setProperty("bootstrap.servers",     "192.168.221.129:9092,192.168.221.130:9092,192.168.221.131:9092")
        kafkaProps.setProperty("group.id", "f1")
        kafkaProps.setProperty("flink.partition-discovery.interval-millis", "5000")
        kafkaProps.setProperty("key.deserializer",    "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    kafkaProps.setProperty("value.deserializer",    "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
        kafkaProps.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
        kafkaProps.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "false")

       val kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String](
          "flinktest",
          new SimpleStringSchema(),
          kafkaProps
       )


        val stream: DataStream[String] = env
          .addSource(kafkaConsumer)

        stream.print();
        val wordCountStream: DataStream[(String, Int)] = stream
          .flatMap(_.split("\\s+"))
          .map(word => (word, 1))
          .keyBy(0)
          .timeWindow(org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time.seconds(5))
          .sum(1)
        println("----------------begin redis");
        wordCountStream.print()

        // Redis 连接信息
        val redisHost = "192.168.221.129"
        val redisPort = 6379

        // 将统计结果写入 Redis
        wordCountStream
          .addSink(new RedisWordCountSink(redisHost, redisPort))

        env.execute("kafkatest")
     }
    }

    
    class RedisWordCountSink(redisHost: String, redisPort: Int) extends RichSinkFunction[(String,   Int)] {
      var jedis: Jedis = _

  // 使用 Flink 的 Logger
      private val LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
   
     override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
       try {
         jedis = new Jedis(redisHost, redisPort)
          // 在 open 方法中输出连接成功的日志
         LOG.info(s"Connected to Redis at $redisHost:$redisPort")
       } catch {
          case e: Exception =>
        // 在 open 方法中输出连接失败的日志
           LOG.error(s"Failed to connect to Redis at $redisHost:$redisPort", e)
       }
     }

     override def invoke(value: (String, Int)): Unit = {
       try {
         println("word:" + value._1 + " count:" + value._2)
         jedis.hset("word_count", value._1, value._2.toString)
       } catch {
         case e: Exception =>
           // 在 invoke 方法中输出写入 Redis 失败的日志
           LOG.error("Failed to write to Redis", e)
       }
     }

     override def close(): Unit = {
       if (jedis != null) {
          jedis.close()
        // 在 close 方法中输出关闭连接的日志
        LOG.info("Closed connection to Redis")
      }
    }
   }
```

I hope to solve this problem